# Gulp: Object #<Readable> has no method 'write' Error

Tags: gulp

I'm getting this error when trying to run my `gulp` command. It worked fine last week. Any reason why I'm getting the following error now?

`TypeError: Object #<Readable> has no method 'write'`

This is what the JS task looks like.

```
// JS task
gulp.task('js', function () {
  var browserified = transform(function(filename) {
    var b = browserify(filename);
    return b.bundle();
  });
  return gulp.src('./src/js/*.js')
    .pipe(browserified)
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./Build/js'))
    .pipe(reload({stream: true}))
});
```

Here's a link to the entire `gulpfile.js`: https://github.com/realph/gulp-zero/blob/master/gulpfile.js

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

What version of `browserify` do you have at the moment? Browserify changed recently to not accept inward streams, just creating some. This would be the correct, adapted code:

```
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var buffer = require('gulp-buffer');

gulp.task('js', function () {
  return browserify({entries:['./src/js/main.js']})
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
    .pipe(buffer())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./Build/js'))
    .pipe(reload({stream: true}))
});
```

**Update** I changed the `filename` to a real file. Note that browserify works best if you just have one file there. If you have to create multiple bundles, please refer to [this article](http://fettblog.eu/gulp-browserify-multiple-bundles/)

Comment: Am I right in thinking that the require should be `require('vinyl-sources')`? In any case, I still can't get this to work. I'm getting this error: `ReferenceError: filename is not defined`.

Comment: Sorry, typo there. It's vinyl-source-stream. That should work

Comment: Getting a `ReferenceError: filename is not defined` error...?

Comment: Alright, `filename` is just a placeholder, you'd have to enter your own files there ;-) Updated it!

Comment: Sorry it's taken me so long to get back to this. I've hardcoded in the filename, just like your example, but I'm now getting this error: `gulp-sourcemap-init: Streaming not supported`.

Comment: Little by little, the bird builds its nest :D Forgot to add gulp-buffer for conversion. Sorry 'bout that.

Comment: Aha! That's what I needed. Thanks a bunch! So, `source` creates a vinyl object and `buffer` converts that vinyl object to a buffered vinyl?

Comment: Yeah. Gulp can work with two formats for their vinyl: Streams or Buffers. Some plugins don't accept streams tough (which is preferred), and plugins shouldn't create buffers. One of the gulp-y downsides. But they're working on it :-)